# Strange issue when clicking buttons in Geb with Spock

Tags: webdriver, spock, geb

The issue is that I'm able to click a button, but the process that the button should execute then just hangs, and doesn't happen. When clicking the `"post"` button, for example, the button should turn black until the post is loaded. Instead, it turns black and then nothing else happens.

If executed manually this is never a problem, and I've never had any problems with Selenium/Java either. Also the error doesn't happen every time. Now and again it works perfectly! Really can't figure out why this is happening.

Here's the page definition and test spec:

Page definition:

```
static at = { title == "HomePage" }

    static content = {

       msgBox{ $("textarea", 0) }

       postBtn{ $("a", class: "js-btn-post") }

       firstPost{ $("div.msg", 2).find("p").text() }

    }
```

Post Spec:

```
def "make a post"() {

        given:
        at HomePage

        when:
        msgBox.click()

        and:
        msgBox.value("This is a test post")

        and:
        postBtn.click()

        then:
        waitFor(10) { firstPost == "This is a test post" }
    }
```

Comment: I may be struggling with similar things where I click, but it just doesn't proceed to the next page.  There's Javascript stuff happening around the buttons and links in many of these cases, so I never knew if I could blame the test or the app.

Comment: Which browser drivers are you using? Have you tried any others?

Comment: Tried in Firefox and Chrome, and neither work. I should have also mentioned that there it is a Javascript button. I do know that the Javascript works though, because as I've mentioned, it works fine when executed manually or with Java/Selenium.

Comment: is it possible that the test clicks on the post button before the handler for the click is registered?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's problem with timer/connection.Try add `waitFor()` to your steps.
Read this: [link](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.0-RC-1/javascript.html#waiting)

Enjoy!!!

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately though that doesn't work. I've tried waiting, but no amount of time will allow it to finish the action. The button just remains blacked out as if it was loading forever.

Comment: hm... I don't know how help you. Sorry.